# Vlookup Based on Data validation lists

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two drop down lists: Cable type and length. So a user could choose "LC-LC SM", and then choose the length "5m". Based on these two inputs, I want to use Vlookup to pull their price.

I have all cables listed in order of type, by length. For example:
[Cables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2p8.jpg)

Cable type and length are the inputs, how do I use those two separate inputs to call the price? This is the input screen; I want to use the Vlookup function in the MSRP cell. 
[Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVDmV.jpg)

Comment: You have `1m` in the cable name, where is that coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I assumed your inputs are in `A2` and `B2` and price data is in `G2:H4`.

```
=VLOOKUP($A2 & " " & $B2 & "m", $G$2:$H$4, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:B4,2,0)
A2 is the display sheet, Sheet1!A2: B4 here is the cable data, 2 is the MSRP values ,0 is the exact values [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnenS.png)